# how to display an activity in Framelayout

Tags: android

I am wrting an android application which displays some buttons dynamically in a linear layout with vertical orientation.When ever we click on any button a new activity should start in the same frame . How can this be possible ? can anyone help me in solving this issue.I will be waiting for reply.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
startActivity(Intent i) or startActivityForResult(Intent i, int flag) or startActivityIfNeeded(Intent i, int flag)
```

Comment: My Qusetion is how to start another activity in the same layout.startActivity() will start in different screen.

Comment: Each Activity will have it's own layout.  That's the way it works.

Comment: Its ok.But if I want to insert a new TextView in the middle and make previously added items to go down

Comment: ViewGroup.addView(View v, int index) that may not make previous ones go down though